# Lua: How can I get the value from a table in the same table?

Tags: lua

```
Code:
Table = {
    x = "test",
    Functions = {
        print(Table.x)
    }
}
```

Error: Main.lua:5: attempt to index a nil value (global 'Table')

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reference lua table member from table member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856047/how-to-reference-lua-table-member-from-table-member)

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding too: right now you call the print function when creating the table, and put its (nil) return value into `Functions`. If you wanted a function instead, which uses `Table` inside, it would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference a table element until the table has been constructed.
You can either add table elements afterwards or use some "syntactic sugar" to pass the table to a function when it is called.

```
Table={x="Test"}
Table.Functions={function()print(Table.x)end}
Table.Functions[1]()
```

Or consider,

```
Table={
x="Test",
xprint = function(self) print(self.x) end
}
Table:xprint() --syntax for Table.xprint(Table)
```

[Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html) gives some good examples of how to do OOP in Lua.